# Set Default controller in usersystem [codeigniter]

Tags: codeigniter

I want to create a simple user system in codeigniter. I have created two controller called admin and login. When user visit my website i.e http://example.com it shows the login page if the user is not logged in. After that when user logged in it redirects to admin page.

But I want to know which controller I should make as a default controller admin or login?

N.B- I am new in codeigniter. I know how MVC works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your default controller should be `login`.

In `application/config/routes.php`,

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login controller name";
```

In login controller's constructor, check if the user is already loggen in'

```
        if(user alerady logged in){
            redirect("admin controller's name");//redirect to admin controller
        }
```

Comment: If user already logged in then i need to redirect to admin page? right?

Comment: yes, in login controller check this in constructor, if the user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 2):

In application/config/routes.php

Replace

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
```

To

```
$route['default_controller'] = "login"; //or whatever you want
```